# Cocos2d - Rendertexture visit noise does not apply glBlendFunc

Tags: objective-c, iphone, opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone

i have a question about cocos2d rendertexture and some custom openGL. I have a method which create a ccrendertexture which render a color and a noise. I use a blendfunc when i visit the noise.

The method has a parameter which define the color which should be render with the noise. When i call the method several times with different colors the rendered textures looks good. But when i call the method with the same color twice, then i get a good looking texture (first one). The second texture looks like that the blendFunc is not applied.

My code for visiting noise:

```
CCSprite *noise = [CCSprite spriteWithImageNamed: @"myNoise.png"];
[noise setBlendFunc:(ccBlendFunc){GL_DST_COLOR, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA}];
noise.position = ccp(textureSize.width/2, textureSize.height/2);
[noise visit];

// 4: Call CCRenderTexture:end
[rt end];

[rt.sprite.texture setAntialiased:YES];

// 5: Create a new Sprite from the texture
return [rt getUIImage];
```

I search in the internet but i don't get solved the problem. Sorry for my bad english. My knowledge in openGL is not the best one.

Comment: until noise is added to another CCNode, it will not be rendered. You must do something similar to [whatever addChild:noise]; first and foremost. Also, dont visit the node unless you have a very specific to do so. The sprite will be visited in the draw cycle immediately after adding it to a parent, and at each update cycle after that.

Comment: I dont add the noise as a child. It's just render a texture which i want as a UIImage

Comment: try setting blendfunc after visit or rt end

Comment: Ok i try it but doesn't work. Is there a problem with the blending function?